# Which player has won the most prize money in professional golf?

Tags: trivia, golf

I am asking about the combined pool of prize money accumulated over a career. Which player has won the most in professional golf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the PGA Tour](https://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.110.html), the answer is, indeed, Tiger Woods.

1. Tiger Woods,     $120,459,468
2. Phil Mickelson,  $90,761,239
3. Jim Furyk,       $71,234,957
4. Vijay Singh,     $71,216,128
5. Dustin Johnson,  $61,755,908